# Rewrite Periods/Dots/(.) in mod_rewrite to plus (+)

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

How do I change a period/dot (.) into a plus (+) of a match using mod_rewrite? My match is `#2`.

This is my rule so far:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-[0-9]*\.shtml$ http://kentwired.com/search/most-popular/?searchphrase=exact&searchword=$2 [L,R=301]
```

With my rules currently,

http://media.www.kentnewsnet.com/media/storage/paper867/news/2009/12/11/News/Tough.Economy.Leaves.Bodies.Unburried-3850836.shtml

becomes

http://kentwired.com/search/most-popular/?searchphrase=exact&searchword=Tough.Economy.Leaves.Bodies.Unburried

but I need

http://kentwired.com/search/most-popular/?searchphrase=exact&searchword=Tough+Economy+Leaves+Bodies+Unburried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.(.*\.shtml)$ /$1+$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^.+/([^/]+)-[0-9]*\.shtml$ http://kentwired.com/search/most-popular/?searchphrase=exact&searchword=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Please bear with me: I'm a Mod-Rewrite-novice to put it mildly, but doesn't your solution simply replace `Tough.Economy.Leaves.Bodies.Unburried` with `Tough+Economy.Leaves.Bodies.Unburried` instead of the desired `Tough+Economy+Leaves+Bodies+Unburried` (which may be impossible in one search and replace)?

Comment: @Bart K.: No, the *N* flag will restart the rewriting process immediately until all dots are replaced. But the *N* flag can also be dangerous as it doesn’t increment the internal redirection counter that is to avoid infinite recursions. So you might also try *L* instead.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation (even though I am not the one asking the question)!

Comment: @Daniel A. White: mod_rewrite is not a good tool to do this kind of work. Better use an external script to do the replacement.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: You can almost use the same with PHP: `if (preg_match('~^.*/(.*)-[0-9]*\.shtml(?:\?|$)~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match)) header('Location: http://kentwired.com/search/most-popular/?searchphrase=exact&searchword='.urlencode(str_replace('.', ' ', $match[1])), true, 301);`